# library not found for -lxml2

Tags: ios, xcode

I had a `'libxml/xmlversion.h' file not found` build error in my iOS Xcode 5.x based project.
Then when i searched in net, I found i need to give the header search path like below.

```
/usr/include/libxml2
```

After giving this path, I am getting following Apple Mach-O linker error,

```
 library not found for -lxml2
```

In the header search path, I found I have given the following path also,

/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneOS.platform/Developer/SDKs/iPhoneOS7.0.sdk/usr/lib/libxml2

I have `libxml2.dylib` in the link binary section.

Could someone help how to solve this issue and make the build successfully?

Comment: If you have `libxml2.dylib` in the *Link Libraries* section then that ought to work.  Please add the complete linker command output (from the build log) to your question.

Comment: Did you add `-lxml2` to Other Linker Flags ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

i think the path should look like this

```
$SDKROOT/usr/include/libxml2
```

that should resolve the problem. $SDKROOT is the key to the right path.

edit:

[sample project:](http://d1xzuxjlafny7l.cloudfront.net/downloads/XMLPerformance.zip)

[and project explanation](http://www.raywenderlich.com/553/xml-tutorial-for-ios-how-to-choose-the-best-xml-parser-for-your-iphone-project)

Comment: I tried this, it throws build error as library not found for -lxml2

Comment: i have added a sample project which uses libxml2. please take a look

Comment: your project compiles fine in the same Mac and Xcode. Verifying what could be the reason in my project.

Comment: When I choose Simulator and compile, it compiles fine, both mine and your project. When I choose device and compile, it gives the same build error as Apple Mach-O linker error:  library not found for -lxml2

Comment: i just compiled on my ipad air. it runs ok. i put [window makeKeyAndVisible]; in applicationDidFinishLaunching.
that project is an example by Apple.

Comment: It is not building in my machine, giving same error Apple Mach-O linker error: library not found for -lxml2. I am having Xcode 5.0.1. Not sure.

Comment: The problem is solved. Looks like libxml2.dylib file is corrupted in my machine. I copied this file from another machine which uses the same xode, in my machine. It worked fine. Thank you!